# How To Secure User Defined Custom Script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, security

We are implementing custom scripting in our application to allow end-users to customize the application business logic using JavaScript. The script code (JavaScript) is entered into the ACE Editor and then saved and retrieved using a standard REST api:

```
function loadScriptFile(scriptID, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.mycompany.com:1337/api/Reports/" + scriptID,
        success: function (contents) {
            callback(contents);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's an example of a custom script that an end-user might enter for the Purchase Order application:

```
function appOnLoad () {
     viewModel.set('description', '<Enter description here>');
}

function appBeforeSave() {
    if (viewModel.get('docTotal') > 500 && viewModel.get('isMgr') == false)
     {
         alert('Only managers can enter POs over $500');
         return false;
     }

    return true;
}

function appAfterSave() {
    return true;
}
```

Empty global 'stub' functions are embedded in the application code for `appOnLoad()`, `appBeforeSave()` and `appAfterSave()` at appropriate places. When the app starts the script is retrieved via REST and initialized using `$.globalEval()` which overrides the stub functions with the functions in the custom script.

Question: Assuming we take precautions to restrict the functions that an authorized end-user can execute in the script what additional security measures should we take to protect the app from external malicious actors?

Comment: It all depends on how this is being used and what needs protected. If this user scripts will be accessed by external users (i.e., people who did not right the custom script) then you've opened up your flood gates. If you can run an arbitrary function then you can do anything. This problem is known as [cross-site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: I would also limit what the user can enter, in terms of the global javascript functions they can execute, such as `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();`, you are naturally going to create security holes letting people run JavaScript, so it is a case of making absolutely sure what they can and cannot write. Also check for infinite loops

Comment: Possibly use HTML5's new `sandbox` attribute on an `IFrame` and limit exposure when rendering the scripts?

Comment: "Check for infinite loops" he says. If you can pull that off you have successfully disproved Alan Turing's theories, ;-)

Comment: The script code can only be accessed (created, modified) by authorized users.